# Обработка событий в Активити

Tags: activity, activity-life-cycle

Какой обработчик событий нужно вставить в активити, чтобы после изменения `layout` автоматически запускалось какое-либо событие без нажатия на что-либо, после проверки состояния флага.

Comment: Есть события на изменения размера и т.п. Но прям глобального обработчика не встречал.

Comment: У меня одна активити, из которой подгружается layout. Как я понимаю всё это происходит в одном потоке main. Но при выполнении операции с layout, как-буд-то фокус с активити уходит.     P.S. При сворачивании и разворачивании окна, фокус выполнения возвращается в метод onResume.

Comment: Методом тыка обнаружил, что onTouch орабатывается постянно. Так что буду пробовать через него)